# How to rotate a rubik's cube as a whole with separate elements rotating as well?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine

Trying to figure out how to rotate the cube as a whole while it being solved with the separate sub cubes

Comment: I've given an answer to this kind of question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155638/objects-not-rotating-with-each-other-rubiks-cube also, maybe you can use empties

Comment: i think the "easiest" solution (if you want to have different animations with all kinds of possibilities and not just one "static" animation) would be to use python or any other "programmable" help like Sverchok, Animation nodes...

Comment: ...or...just start thinking about it...you make it with empties as moonboots proposed, and then make one animation/rotation and at the end of each animation you just "reset" all animations of the cubes and just changes the textures/materials accordingly. But also for changing "just" the materials you need some kind of programmable help.

Comment: Here's my solution for multiple cubes using Geometry Nodes: [Realistically randomize Rubik's Cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/291631/60486) And here's older solutions using Animation Nodes: [Animation Nodes Rubik's Cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/77756/60486)